# Javascript:showDiv add anchor #top

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a javascript to hide and show when an image is clicked on.  The problem when the image is clicked it doesn't go to the top of the page.  I tried adding an anchor #top but can't get it to work.  Can someone show me how to do this with the code provided?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var option = 'coke';
    var url = window.location.href;
    option = url.match(/option=(.*)/)[1];
    showDiv(option);
  });
  function showDiv(option) {
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $('#' + option).show();
  }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .boxes {
  display: none;
  }
</style>
<a name="top"></a>
<div class="boxes" id="coke"><img src="image1.gif"></div>
<div class="boxes" id="bubble-tea"><img src="image2.gif"> </div>
<div class="boxes" id="milk"><img src="image3.gif"> </div>
<p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('coke')"><img src="image1.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('bubble-tea')"><img src="image2.gif"></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:showDiv('milk')"><img src="image3.gif"></a></li>
</ul>
</p>
```

Comment: Do we have to use the code provided or can it be redone to a much better way of getting the job done?

Comment: Oh ok...because a better way would be to just use one div and one anchor and just change the source of the anchor. Its more flexible that way because you won't need to have many divs created and hiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<a href="javascript:showDiv('coke')">
```

changed to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showDiv('coke')">
```